# Iterating through nested dict in a particular order with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dict which has lists as well as dict in it as given below.

```
m = {'abc': 
      {'bcd': [
               {'cde':'100','def':'200','efg':'300'},
               {'cde':'3000','def':'500','efg':'4000'}
              ], 
       'ghi': 
         {'mnc': [
                  {'xyz':'8827382','mnx':'e838','wyew':'2232'}
                 ]
         }
       }
     }
```

My requirement is to match mnx key and if the value is `'e838'` then get the value of the other keys in that particular dict. So from the above example I may require the value of `xyz` key.

For this, I have created a recursive looping function as given below which is working. However my question is whether there is a better / easy way to do it. Also what can be done in the same code if I need to get all the values with key mnx. Thanks.

Note: I am converting an XML into dict with the help of jxmlease lib.

```
def iterate_dict(dict1,key1,val1):
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        if key == key1 and value == val1:
            return dict1
        if isinstance(value,list):
            for item1 in value:
                if isinstance(item1,dict):
                    for k,v in item1.items():
                        if k == key1 and v == val1:
                            return item1
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            for key,var in value.items():
                if key == key1 and var == val1:
                    return value
                else:
                    return iterate_dict(value,key1,val1)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know where the `mnx` key is going to be? If not, the XML library you are using to convert the XML into a dictionary should be able to help you find `mnx`

Comment: Better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do you want the output to contain if a dict containing `'mnx'` is not a bottom-level dict, i.e., it contains lists &/or dicts? Or won't that ever happen?

Comment: "what can be done in the same code if I need to get all the values with key mnx". Do you mean that you may want all of the dicts that contain the key 'mnx' with the specified value ('e838' in your example)? Would you _also_ like to be able to get all of the dicts that contain the key 'mnx', no matter what the value is? All of these things may be done, with code that's simpler & more efficient than you current code, but I need the answers to my questions before I can post my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can *sort of* "flatten" the dict into a list of dicts and then query as necessary:

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    flattened = []
    current = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flattened.extend(flatten_dict(v))
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            flattened.extend(sum((flatten_dict(v_d) for v_d in v), []))
        else:
            current[k] = v
    if len(current) > 0:
        flattened = [current] + flattened
    return flattened

def values_in_flattened(flattened, key):
    return list(filter(None, (d.get(key, None) for d in flattened))) or None

m = {'abc': {'bcd':[{'cde':'100','def':'200','efg':'300'},{'cde':'3000','def':'500','efg':'4000'}], 'ghi':{'mnc':[{'xyz':'8827382','mnx':'e838','wyew':'2232'}]}}}
mf = flatten_dict(m)
efg_vals = values_in_flattened(mf, 'efg')
print(mf)
print(efg_vals)

>>>
[{'xyz': '8827382', 'mnx': 'e838', 'wyew': '2232'}, {'def': '200', 'efg': '300', 'cde': '100'}, {'def': '500', 'efg': '4000', 'cde': '3000'}]
['300', '4000']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m['abc']['bcd'] + m['abc']['ghi']['mnc']
```

out:

```
[{'cde': '100', 'def': '200', 'efg': '300'},
 {'cde': '3000', 'def': '500', 'efg': '4000'},
 {'mnx': 'e838', 'wyew': '2232', 'xyz': '8827382'}]
```

you should build a list of dict to iterate, rather than use raw data.

Answer (score 0):

This code does the searching using recursive generators, so it will yield all the solutions as it finds them.

When `iterate_dict` finds a dict with the desired (key, value) pair it calls `filter_dict`, which creates a new dict to contain the output. This new dict contains the items of the dict passed to `filter_dict` except that it filters out the desired (key, value) pair, it also filters out any lists or dicts that that dict may contain.  However, `iterate_dict` will recursively process those lists or dicts looking for further matches. If you don't want `iterate_dict` to look for further matches, it's easy to modify the code so that it doesn't do that; please see below.

If you want to search for dicts that contain the desired key and don't care about the value associated with that key you can pass `None` as the `val` argument, or just omit that arg.

I've modified your data slightly so we can test the recursive search for further matches in a dict that contains a match.

```
def filter_dict(d, key):
    return {k: v for k, v in d.items() 
        if k != key and not isinstance(v, (dict, list))}

def iterate_dict(d, key, val=None):
    if key in d and (val is None or d[key] == val):
        yield filter_dict(d, key)
    yield from iterate_list(d.values(), key, val)

def iterate_list(seq, key, val):
    for v in seq:
        if isinstance(v, list):
            yield from iterate_list(v, key, val)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from iterate_dict(v, key, val)

# test

data = {
    'abc': {
        'bcd': [
            {'cde':'100', 'def':'200', 'efg':'300'},
            {'cde':'3000', 'def':'500', 'efg':'4000'},
            {'abc': '1', 'mnx': '2', 'ijk': '3', 
                'zzz': {'xyzz':'44', 'mnx':'e838', 'yew':'55'}
            },
        ], 
        'ghi': {
            'mnc': [
                {'xyz':'8827382', 'mnx':'e838', 'wyew':'2232'}
            ]
        }
    }
}

for d in iterate_dict(data, 'mnx', 'e838'):
    print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'yew': '55', 'xyzz': '44'}
{'xyz': '8827382', 'wyew': '2232'}
```

Here's a search that looks for all dicts containing the `'mnx'` key:

```
for d in iterate_dict(data, 'mnx'):
    print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'ijk': '3', 'abc': '1'}
{'xyzz': '44', 'yew': '55'}
{'wyew': '2232', 'xyz': '8827382'}
```

If you *don't* want each dict to be recursively searched for further matches once a match has been found in it, just change `iterate_dict` to:

```
def iterate_dict(d, key, val=None):
    if key in d and (val is None or d[key] == val):
        yield filter_dict(d, key)
    else:
        yield from iterate_list(d.values(), key, val)
```

Comment: I decided to post this code anyway without waiting for answers to my questions. It's getting late here, and you may need this code before I get back. :)